# Use function arguments in lm formula within function environment

Tags: r

Consider the following function:

```
lm_eqn <- function(df, indep, dep){
  
  lm(formula = dep ~ indep, data = df)
}

lm_eqn(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)  ## does not work, throws error.
```

I tried to quote/unquote in several ways. None of those were succesful, throwing different errors and none of them were exactly helpful for me:

Using `deparse(substitute(dep))`

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Using `quo(dep)` or `enquo(dep)` or `expr(dep)`

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dep ~ indep, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : object is not a matrix

Using above with unquoting using `!!`:

> Error in !dep : invalid argument type

Specifying the variable names for the formula within the function body works:

```
lm_eqn2 <- function(df){
  
     lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)
}

lm_eqn2(iris)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = df)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#     6.5262      -0.2234
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quote the input, and then use `eval(as.name())` inside the function.

```
lm_eqn <- function(df, indep, dep){

  lm(formula = eval(as.name(dep)) ~ eval(as.name(indep)), data = df)
}

lm_eqn(iris, 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')
```

Comment: this looks very good. am on my way will have a look very soon. already many thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the formula in the output pretty, you can call `substitute` on the whole call, which will interpolate the variable names, then call `eval` on the result to run it:

```r
lm_eqn <- function(data, x, y){
    eval(substitute(
        lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data)
    ))
}

lm_eqn(iris, Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)    # <- pretty!
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      6.5262      -0.2234
```

Or to make it all really simple (and a lot more flexible), just pass a formula directly:

```r
lm_frm <- function(data, formula){
    lm(formula, data)
}

lm_frm(iris, Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = formula, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
#>      6.5262      -0.2234
```

Wrapping the `lm` call in `eval(substitute(...))` will fix the stored call structure with this approach, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both quoted and unquoted column names with the following `substitute` trick taken from the source of function `library`, which also accepts both.

```
lm_eqn <- function(df, indep, dep){
  indep <- as.character(substitute(indep))
  dep <- as.character(substitute(dep))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(dep, indep, sep = "~"))
  lm(fmla, data = df)
}

lm_eqn(iris, 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = fmla, data = df)
#
#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#     3.41895      -0.06188  
#

lm_eqn(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = fmla, data = df)
#
#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Length  
#     3.41895      -0.06188  
#
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a neat trick!  I will however accept @bobbel's answer because they answered earlier and also have less rep

Answer (score 3):

Approach without quotes:

```
> lm_eqn(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)

Call:
lm(formula = dep ~ indep, data = df_lm)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        indep  
    3.41895     -0.06188
```

**Caveat**: Passing object names without quotes is visually pleasant, but generally frowned upon because it *can* introduce instability.

#### Code

```
lm_eqn <- function(df_lm, indep, dep){
    df_lm <- eval(as.name(deparse(substitute(df_lm))))
    indep <- df_lm[, grep(deparse(substitute(indep)), colnames(df_lm))]
    dep <- df_lm[, grep(deparse(substitute(dep)), colnames(df_lm))]

    lm(formula = dep ~ indep, data = df_lm)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and also very interesting. I admit I prefer the other solutions though ;)