# Base R - functions general question - Outputting a variable with an input name

Tags: r

Is there a way I can write an input name for a variable I want to output in a function? I currently have this very simple example:

```
power <- function(value1,value2) {
  sumValues <<- value1 + value2
}
power(value1 = 2, value2 = 3)
```

Which returns a variable calles sumValues with the answer.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
power <- function(value1,value2,Variable_name) {
  Variable_name <<- value1 + value2
}
power(value1 = 2, value2 = 3, Varieble_name = SumofValues)
```

Which would return me a variable after what I named, in this case SumofValues.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I couldn't find an answer after searching, or rather, I didn't know how to look for it.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856711/arguments-for-lm-in-closure-r/) might be related if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Roman I believe it is related in the way to pass `Variable_name` quoted or unquoted. But then it's just an `assign` trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an `assign` trick. See `help("assign")`.

```
power <- function(value1, value2, Variable_name) {
  Variable_name <- as.character(substitute(Variable_name))
  assign(Variable_name, value1 + value2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

power(value1 = 2, value2 = 3, Variable_name = SumofValues)

SumofValues
#[1] 5
```

And please don't use `<<-` unless you have a really, really good reason to do so. And even in that case, make sure you are not trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

As Rui said, using `<<-` is a bad idea.  But you don't even need `assign()`.  Just write your assignment in the usual way:

```
power <- function(value1,value2) {
  value1 + value2
}
SumofValues <- power(value1 = 2, value2 = 3)
```

If you've got a lot of different names, then use them to name elements in a list.  For example,

```
names <- c("SumofValues", "OtherName")
result <- list()
result[[names[1]]] <- power(2, 3)
result[[names[2]]] <- power(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval(parse(text=))` to do this.

```
power <- function(value1,value2,Variable_name) {
  textpar <- paste0(Variable_name," <<- ",value1," + ",value2)
  eval(parse(text = textpar))
}
power(value1 = 2, value2 = 3, Variable_name = "SumofValues")
SumofValues
5
```